# How to I use bitwise operators to compare two unsigned integers?

Tags: c, boolean, logic

How do I go about in using bitwise operators to see which is the greater of two unsigned integers, without using any arithmetic operators or comparison operators?

Comment: signed or unsigned integers? 64 bit, 32 bit, 16 bit or 8 bit? What have you tried?

Comment: sorry its unsigned.

Comment: **Hint:** In C, zero is false, non-zero is true.  That's the only way you're going to obtain a branch without a comparison operator.

Comment: See also https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compute-the-minimum-or-maximum-max-of-two-integers-without-branching/

Comment: To compare two unsigned integers using bitwise operations, you need to find the most significant bit where the two differ in their binary representation.  Shift and mask in a loop.  Slow — but that's why computers provide the operations as a single opcode and don't require you to do homework exercises like this.

Comment: Hints: (1) the bits that have the same value in both inputs do not affect the answer.  (2) An exclusive or (`^`) operation will tell you which bits differ.  (3) Among the bits where the inputs differ, the most significant one alone determines which input (if either) is larger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's us consider two integers 4 (0100) and 3 (0011). We need to generate the biggest-sub-bits-series which differentiate the two integers, for example above it is 0100 ( since the third bit is different ), then we can simply know which is bigger by making bit AND operation:

```
0100 & 0100 = 0100 > 0  
0011 & 0100 = 0
```

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a, b;

  printf("Enter two numbers\n");
  scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);

  int diff = a ^ b;
  if (diff)  //true means both are not equal
  {
    diff = diff | (diff >> 1);
    diff |= diff >> 2;
    diff |= diff >> 4;
    diff |= diff >> 8;
    diff |= diff >> 16;
    diff ^= diff >> 1;

    int res = (a & diff) ? 1 : 0;

    if (res)
        printf("%d greater than %d", a, b);
    else
        printf("%d greater than %d", b, a);
   }

  else //both equal
  {
    printf("Both are equal\n");
    return 0;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I checked in my system, it worked (Ubuntu).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I will do the math later when I get home from work today. At least I’ll have some sort of guide. This is really helpful.

Comment: @Ryanv048  You are welcome. Please upvote the answer and accept , if it is helpful .

Comment: I was curious about your use of a _signed_ `int`. So, I added a test function derived from your algorithm to my test program [and one that uses unsigned]. Your original code fails for values that differ in the sign bit. When you switch to unsigned, it works fine. So, you may want to change your code to use `unsigned int`.

Comment: @CraigEstey  Yes, you are correct. Code does not work for numbers with different sign. But the question ---> "greater of two unsigned integers"

Answer (score 0):

If you were dealing with the decimal representation of numbers, you'd say the one with the most digits is the larger one.

What if two numbers have the same number of digits? Well, you compare each digit in turn, starting with the most significant.

In decimal, that would be hard to while meeting your requirements. But in binary, we can perform simple truth tests. As such, this approach can be used here.

```
+---+---+---+---+       +---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |  6    | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |  6
+---+---+---+---+       +---+---+---+---+
  →   ↑            ↑      →   →   ↑        ↑
+---+---+---+---+       +---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |  2    | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |  4
+---+---+---+---+       +---+---+---+---+
```

As such, this works for unsigned integers of the same size:

1. Isolate the most significant bit of each number.
2. If they're different, which ever has the bit set is larger.
3. If not, repeat for the next most significant bit.

---

There is an even simpler solution that involves finding the exclusive-or of the two input numbers.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. When you say isolate the most significant, you mean by using the shift operator. To that right that is.

Answer (score -2):

Using XOR (exclusive OR) and SHL (shift left) in a loop will do the job.

XOR (in C: `^`) is the normal way [in low level H/W] to test for equality. It's a basic logic gate.

If the XOR of two numbers is zero, they are equal.

But, the XOR of two numbers produces a bit mask where if any of the bits in two numbers are different the corresponding XOR bit is a 1 (0 otherwise).

By shifting and masking against the MSB, we can find the leftmost bit that is different.

Here's some code that illustrates that. It has a diagnostic test so you can verify your function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned int u32;

// RETURNS -1=a<b, 0=a==b, +1=a>b
int
cmpxor(u32 a,u32 b)
{
    u32 xor;
    u32 msb;
    int cmp = 0;

    // get a mask for the most signifcant bit
    msb = 1u << 31;

    // which bits are different
    xor = a ^ b;

    while (xor != 0) {
        // is the most significant bit different? if so, we are done
        if (xor & msb) {
            if (a & msb)
                cmp = 1;
            else
                cmp = -1;
            break;
        }

        xor <<= 1;
        a <<= 1;
    }

    return cmp;
}

int
cmpstd(u32 a,u32 b)
{
    int cmp = 0;

    if (a < b)
        cmp = -1;
    if (a > b)
        cmp = 1;

    return cmp;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    u32 a;
    u32 b;
    int cmpx;
    int cmps;
    u32 opt_L = 0;
    int code = 0;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'L':
            opt_L = (*cp != 0) ? atoll(cp) : 65536;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (opt_L == 0)
        opt_L = 1024;

    for (a = 0;  a < opt_L;  ++a) {
        for (b = 0;  b < opt_L;  ++b) {
            cmps = cmpstd(a,b);
            cmpx = cmpxor(a,b);
            if (cmps != cmpx) {
                printf("a=%8.8X b=%8.8X cmps=%d cmpx=%d\n",
                    a,b,cmps,cmpx);
                code = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (code)
            break;
    }

    if (code == 0)
        printf("complete\n");

    return code;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I've enhanced the diagnostic test suite. And, I added some benchmarking.

I also added two functions derived from Krishna's answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef unsigned long long u64;

u32 opt_L = 0;
int opt_e;                              // number of errors to show per func
int opt_k;                              // don't stop next test if error
int opt_v;                              // show all values

// RETURNS -1=a<b, 0=a==b, +1=a>b
int
cmpxor(u32 a,u32 b)
{
    u32 xor;
    u32 msb;
    int cmp = 0;

    // get a mask for the most signifcant bit
    msb = 1u << 31;

    // which bits are different
    xor = a ^ b;

    while (xor != 0) {
        // is the most significant bit different? if so, we are done
        if (xor & msb) {
            if (a & msb)
                cmp = 1;
            else
                cmp = -1;
            break;
        }

        xor <<= 1;
        a <<= 1;
    }

    return cmp;
}

int
cmpstd(u32 a,u32 b)
{
    int cmp = 0;

    if (a < b)
        cmp = -1;
    if (a > b)
        cmp = 1;

    return cmp;
}

int
cmpki(int a, int b)
{
    int diff = a ^ b;
    int res;

    do {
        // Both are equal
        if (diff == 0) {
            res = 0;
            break;
        }

        diff = diff | (diff >> 1);
        diff |= diff >> 2;
        diff |= diff >> 4;
        diff |= diff >> 8;
        diff |= diff >> 16;
        diff ^= diff >> 1;

        // Conditonal operator is not a relational operator
        res = (a & diff) ? 1 : -1;
    } while (0);

    return res;
}

int
cmpku(u32 a, u32 b)
{
    u32 diff = a ^ b;
    int res;

    do {
        // Both are equal
        if (diff == 0) {
            res = 0;
            break;
        }

        diff = diff | (diff >> 1);
        diff |= diff >> 2;
        diff |= diff >> 4;
        diff |= diff >> 8;
        diff |= diff >> 16;
        diff ^= diff >> 1;

        // Conditonal operator is not a relational operator
        res = (a & diff) ? 1 : -1;
    } while (0);

    return res;
}

double tsczero;
double tscbeg;

double
tscget(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    double sec;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
    sec = ts.tv_nsec;
    sec /= 1e9;
    sec += ts.tv_sec;

    if (tsczero == 0)
        tsczero = sec;

    sec -= tsczero;

    return sec;
}

#define msgbeg(_fmt...) \
    do { \
        tscbeg = tscget(); \
        printf("%13.9f ",tscbeg); \
        printf(_fmt); \
        fflush(stdout); \
    } while (0)

void
msgend(void)
{

    double tscend = tscget();
    printf(" (ELAPSED: %.9f)\n",tscend - tscbeg);
}

typedef struct {
    int (*tst_fnc)(u32,u32);
    const char *tst_tag;
} tst_t;

tst_t tstlist[] = {
    { .tst_tag = "cmpxor", .tst_fnc = (void *) cmpxor },
    { .tst_tag = "cmpki", .tst_fnc = (void *) cmpki },
    { .tst_tag = "cmpku", .tst_fnc = (void *) cmpku },
    { .tst_tag = NULL }
};
int taglen;

int
dotest(tst_t *tst,u64 lo,u64 hi,u32 inc)
{
    u64 a;
    u64 b;
    int cmpx;
    int cmps;
    int badflg;
    int hangflg = 1;
    int ecnt = 0;

    msgbeg("dotest: %-*s %8.8llX/%8.8llX/%8.8X",taglen,tst->tst_tag,lo,hi,inc);

    for (a = lo;  a <= hi;  a += inc) {
        for (b = lo;  b <= hi;  b += inc) {
            cmps = cmpstd(a,b);
            cmpx = tst->tst_fnc(a,b);

            badflg = (cmps != cmpx);

            if (badflg || opt_v) {
                if (hangflg) {
                    hangflg = 0;
                    printf("\n");
                }

                printf("%-*s: %s a=%8.8llX b=%8.8llX cmps=%d cmpx=%d\n",
                    taglen,tst->tst_tag,badflg ? "FAIL" : "PASS",a,b,cmps,cmpx);

                if (badflg)
                    ++ecnt;

                if (opt_v)
                    continue;

                if (ecnt >= opt_e)
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (opt_v)
            continue;

        if (ecnt >= opt_e)
            break;
    }

    if (ecnt || opt_v) {
        if (hangflg)
            printf("\n");
        printf("%-*s: %d errors",taglen,tst->tst_tag,ecnt);
    }

    msgend();

    if (ecnt)
        ecnt = 1;

    return ecnt;
}

typedef struct {
    u32 rng_lo;
    u32 rng_hi;
    u32 rng_inc;
} rng_t;

rng_t rnglist[] = {
    { .rng_lo = 0x00000000, .rng_hi = 0x000000FF,   .rng_inc = 1 },
    { .rng_lo = 0x01000000, .rng_hi = 0xFFFFFFFF,   .rng_inc = 0x01000000 },
    { .rng_inc = 0 }
};

int
dorange(rng_t *rng)
{
    tst_t *tst;
    int code = 0;

    for (tst = tstlist;  tst->tst_tag != NULL;  ++tst) {
        code = dotest(tst,rng->rng_lo,rng->rng_hi,rng->rng_inc);
        if (! opt_k) {
            if (code)
                break;
        }
    }

    return code;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int code = 0;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        char *cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        cp += 2;
        switch (cp[-1]) {
        case 'e':
            opt_e = (*cp != 0) ? atoi(cp) : 0x7FFFFFFF;
            break;
        case 'k':
            opt_k = ! opt_k;
            break;
        case 'L':
            opt_L = (*cp != 0) ? atoll(cp) : 65536;
            break;
        case 'v':
            opt_v = ! opt_v;
            break;
        }
    }

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    if (opt_L == 0)
        opt_L = 256;

    if (opt_e == 0)
        opt_e = 1;
    if (opt_v)
        opt_e = 0x7FFFFFFF;

    // get max length of function name
    for (tst_t *tst = tstlist;  tst->tst_tag != NULL;  ++tst) {
        int curlen = strlen(tst->tst_tag);
        if (curlen > taglen)
            taglen = curlen;
    }

    // do all test ranges
    for (rng_t *rng = rnglist;  rng->rng_inc != 0;  ++rng) {
        code = dorange(rng);
        if (code)
            break;
    }

    if (code == 0)
        printf("complete\n");

    return code;
}
```

---

Here's the test output:

```
  0.000000000 dotest: cmpxor 00000000/000000FF/00000001 (ELAPSED: 0.001531766)
  0.001538215 dotest: cmpki  00000000/000000FF/00000001 (ELAPSED: 0.000467471)
  0.002008009 dotest: cmpku  00000000/000000FF/00000001 (ELAPSED: 0.000475924)
  0.002488059 dotest: cmpxor 01000000/FFFFFFFF/01000000 (ELAPSED: 0.000398438)
  0.002888709 dotest: cmpki  01000000/FFFFFFFF/01000000
cmpki : FAIL a=80000000 b=01000000 cmps=1 cmpx=-1
cmpki : 1 errors (ELAPSED: 0.000237286)
  0.003127983 dotest: cmpku  01000000/FFFFFFFF/01000000 (ELAPSED: 0.000467515)
complete
```

The reason I enhanced the test suite was that I felt the use of a *signed* `int` in `cmpki` [Krishna's original algorithm] might have issues for numbers with the sign bit set [because of the semantics of an *arithmetic* right shift vs. a *logical* right shift]. And, because the original problem stated that the numbers were unsigned.

I added an unsigned version and that fixed the issue.

Comment: @CraigEstey You should not use comparison operators . `while (xor != 0)`  -->Comparison

Comment: Thanks Craig for the help, my apologies also for the late reply. It gives me a guide on what to do. I really appreciate it.

Comment: We should not use any comparison operator.  You have used `<` , `>`, `==`  and `!=` operators.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula I only used `xor != 0` [in the `while`]. Use of _any_ `if/while/?:` _is_ a comparison even if it's `if (val)`--one can't get around that. You used `if (diff == 0)`. I did _not_ use `<` or `>`. If you're referring to `cmpstd`, that is just part of the unit test suite to provide a reference for validation of the "real" code (e.g. `cmpxor` [and `cmpki/cmpku`]). As I mentioned, XOR is a basic logic gate that is used in hardware for testing for equality/inequality. The problem is really one of how to use basic logic. The problem only wants `gt`, but we both went for `cmp`

Comment: @CraigEstey  Thank you for pointiing. I edited it.  I removed the usage of `==` operator. In `if(res)  if(diff)` ------> Comparison operators are not used